# What does the while loop do for the pg_fetch_array($result) such that you get next rows and end

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql, while-loop

I'm a php dev, been coding all this while with the help of postgresql. I searched the web, but couldn't find an answer. I'm really curious. In this code below, where is the 'true' flag stored? Isn't the argument for while loop supposed to be a comparison statement which returns a boolean value, instead of a variable/array assignment statement? I plan to use the correct answer to find better ways to code my app and impress my boss.

```php
$result = pg_query($query);

while($myrow = pg_fetch_array($result)){
    $var1 = $myrow[0];
    $var2 = $myrow[1];

    //do some magic with the variables

}
```

Comment: The value of an assignment expression _is_ the assigned value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [official docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) of `pg_fetch_array()`

> An array indexed numerically (beginning with 0) or associatively
>   (indexed by field name), or both. Each value in the array is
>   represented as a string. Database NULL values are returned as NULL.
>
> FALSE is returned if row exceeds the number of rows in the set, there
>   are no more rows, or on any other error.

So if there is no more rows it returns FALSE, if there is a rows return numerically or associative array which while loop evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: How does it fetch next rows? How does it know that row 45 is fetched, in the next while loop iteration, need to fetch row 46 for example?